# How to select the largest image from picture srcset using Nokogiri

Tags: html, css, ruby, nokogiri

Say I have this...

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://example.com/a-1x.jpg 1x, https://example.com/a-2x.jpg 2x" media="(min-width: 1200px)">
  <source srcset="https://example.com/b-1x.jpg 1x, https://example.com/b-2x.jpg 2x" media="(min-width: 1200px)">
  <source srcset="https://example.com/c-1x.jpg 1x, https://example.com/c-2x.jpg 2x" media="(min-width: 992px)">
  <source srcset="https://example.com/d-1x.jpg 1x, https://example.com/d-2x.jpg 2x" media=" (min-width: 768px)">
  <source srcset="https://example.com/e-1x.jpg 1x, https://example.com/e-2x.jpg 2x" media="(min-width: 480px)">
  <img src="https://example.com/a-2x.jpg">
</picture>
```

I have a toolchain using Nokogiri for selecting elements on a page. It already can handle a simple `img[src]` and even any element with a background-image in an inline style...

Any suggestions on **how to pick the largest element from that picture set using Nokogiri / Ruby**?

According to [MDN, the sources are not in any defined order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture).

Comment: Largest as in style? Just read the `media` attribute, pull out the `(\d+)px` part and go for it. Hint: `max_by`.

Comment: Interesting idea! Thanks. This works well if the media selectors are all min-width... but would require extra parsing if max-width were used too.

I guess also need to parse out the 1x and 2x densities?!

There is no guarantee that the largest image is in the largest min-width media selector. Hypothetically, the largest could only contain a 1x... But I guess thats a bit edge-case-y...